# ContractClassFor attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

What is and when would I use

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof())]
```

MSDN explanation is not telling me much about it. Thank you,

Comment: Is there a reason why you would _want_ to use it? Typically people dont just include the attribute for funsies, and typically attributes just represent metadata, so they don't actually DO anything.

Comment: @Tejs, this attribute is something that I see in the code that I have to deal with and understand. As well I know that in MVC attributes actually do stuff like validation/authorization etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This attribute allows you to define Code Contract conditions for an interface.  For more detail, the following site might be useful http://devjourney.com/blog/code-contracts-part-5-abstract-types-and-interfaces/

Update:  It seems Kevin has deleted the content.  A cache of the content can be found here: http://web.archive.org/web/20120105070912/http://devjourney.com/blog/code-contracts-part-5-abstract-types-and-interfaces/